# How should I store passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-protection, digest-authentication, password-encryption

I have a system that needs logins, but who i'm building it for is requiring the transmission of the passwords during login to be very secure (even using SSL). So i'm using a variant of the Digest access authentication to transmit login requests. The only problem i'm having now is how to store the passwords on the database (in a secure salted hash preferably) so they can be used with the digest request, and the password at no point is in an nonhashed format, except on the clients browser for a few seconds.

So, in a nutshell, how can I store passwords securely but allow for a digest (with a different and ever changing nonce to the database's salt) to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, this mechanism sends something like:

```
hash(nonce + hash(password + salt))
```

So on the server, you just need to store `hash(password + salt)` and `salt`.

Comment: that was my initial thought, but in order to do that, i'd have to transmit the salt that the passwords are secured with. Wouldn't that compromise the security of the passwords?

Comment: @cgoddard: No.  In a properly-designed system, knowing the salt won't help an attacker.

Comment: Ah good, but how do you mean properly-designed? What factors do I need to take into account?

Comment: @cgoddard: In essence, you need to ensure that each password is hashed with a unique salt, with "reasonable" amounts of entropy used to generate the salt.  But I'm not anything close to an expert in this field, so please don't take my answer as the final word!  (So much so in fact, that I'd echo the standard advice: Don't roll your own crypto/security system unless you're an expert.)

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. That should be sufficient though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the source code of [this](http://search.cpan.org/~vidul/Linux-usermod-0.69/usermod.pm) Perl module; it manages *nix accounts.